# Why does my class member not exist?

Tags: c++

I wrote a map class:

```
typedef int (& func(const std::string &));

template <class t_child>
class map final
{
    std::vector<t_child> m_table;
    const func m_hasher;
public:
    explicit map(const func hasher) : m_hasher(hasher) {}
    map(const map &copy) = delete;
    ~map();
    map &operator=(const map&) = delete;
    //***
};
```

But I am getting the error:

```
map.hpp:15: error: class ‘map<t_child>’ does not have any field named ‘m_hasher’
     explicit map(const func hasher) : m_hasher(hasher) {}
                                       ^~~~~~~~
```

What's wrong? Why does it not exist?

Comment: Oh, it exists. It's just not a class member. `func`'s type is a function. It's as if you declared a class method called `size()`, and attempted to initialize `size(something)` in the constructor.

Comment: How to initialize it in the initialized list?

Comment: You can't. You can't initialize functions or class methods. C++ does not work this way. If you intend for `m_hasher` to be a class member which is a ***pointer*** to a function, you need to declare it, as such.

Comment: I see, thank you for answer

Comment: If you wanted the type to be a reference to function, that would be spelled `typedef int (&func)(const std::string&);`. But references to functions are rare, and I don't know any advantage they have over pointers to functions, except maybe allowing a template that uses "reference to anything".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize this isn't a great answer, but I can tell you a quick way to get it to work if that's what you want.

I usually use `<functional>` for things like this since it's generally easier to remember than function pointer grammar. I have the following compiling.

```
#include <string>
#include <functional>

using func = std::function<int(std::string&)>;

template <class t_child>
class map final
{
    std::vector<t_child> m_table;
    const func m_hasher;
public:
    explicit map(const func hasher) : m_hasher(hasher) {}
    map(const map &copy) = delete;
    ~map();
    map &operator=(const map&) = delete;
    //***                                                                                                                                                                                          
};

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, it's a great answer for my task. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is not necessarily related to your problem, but you may also use the standard [unordered_map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/) class and inherit it if needed.

Comment: I can't, unfortunately